# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have followed the steps from Tensorflow For Poets ([link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0/%22Link%22)) to train my own dataset using tensorflow, and getting very good prediction result.This provides me retrained.py, label_images.py, retrained_graph.pb, retrained_labels.txt files.So i have my own model graph and label file.

After that i have downloaded Tensorflow Example Project for iOS from github. The project runs successfully in iOS platform. but when i am using my own retrained_graph.pb, retrained_labels.txt file on behalf of examples model and label file , i am getting error as following -

Errors :

Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

[[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false]]

and ,

Couldn't load model: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'DecodeJpeg' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:

[[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false]]

Can you help me please ? I have been searching a long time for it .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're placing the image decoding operation on the GPU, while this op is available only for the execution on the CPU.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

> If you would like TensorFlow to automatically choose an existing and supported device to run the operations in case the specified one doesn't exist, you can set `allow_soft_placement` to True in the configuration option when creating the session.

therefore, you simply have to change your session initialization with

```
 tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
  allow_soft_placement=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow on iOS is a Subset of PC's, It doesn't contain some functions that use too much memory.

You can transform you pb-file to which CoreML supports.

This Tool may help you [tf-coreml](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml)